# Как заставить бота ждать сообщение и потом реагировать на него?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Доброго времени суток!

Пишу бота для телеграмма, пытался сделать реферальную систему и столкнулся с проблемой, что не могу заставить бота ждать сообщение от юзера и соответственно бот никак не реагирует на сообщения

```
        i = db.user_money(message.from_user.id)
        r = i[5]
        ### эти строки просто достают код из базы данных, они работают нормально###

        elif call.data == 'Referal':

        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Мой реф код", callback_data='My ref')
        item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Ввести код друга", callback_data='Addref')
        item3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("⬅️Назад", callback_data='Nazad v main')
        markup.add(item1, item2, item3)

        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, ' Реферальная программа\n\n Наш бот имеет 
        реферальную сестему! Попроси друга ввести ваш код и получайте бонус!', reply_markup=markup)
        bot.delete_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id)

        elif call.data == 'Addref':


        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("⬅️Назад", callback_data='Referal')
        markup.add(item1)

        if call.message.chat.id == r:      ### r - это переменная в которую записан код, она работает правильно###

            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'успех!!', reply_markup=markup)
        else:
            bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'не подходит!', reply_markup=markup)

        bot.delete_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id)
```

в итоге бот после нажатия на кнопку "Ввести код друга" просто сразу выдаёт 'не подходит!' и не реагирует на сообщения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте команду `bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, func)`
Показую на примере:

```py
    def code(message):
        msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Введите ваш код")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg,active)
    def active(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id," Вы успешно ввели код")
```

Comment: Вот так?




`msg = bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,"Введите ваш код")
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg,active)

            def active(message):
            if msg == r:
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'успех!', reply_markup=markup)
            else:
                bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'не успех!', reply_markup=markup)

            bot.delete_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id)`

Comment: Просто попробуйте, если не получиться то помогу. Хорошо?

Comment: Если же получиться то поставьте зелёную галочку чтобы все знали что это работает

Comment: получаю ошибку - local variable 'active' referenced before assignment

Comment: На какую строку кода ссылаеться?  Попробуйте переименовать функцию active и не забудьте ето везде указать, и ета функция должна бить в поле bot.polling

Comment: на эту bot.register_next_step_handler(msg,active)

Comment: Так щас у себя протестирую или же посмотрю старый код

Comment: А можете скинуть сам этот кусок кода

Comment: `elif call.data == 'Addref':

            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
            item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("⬅️Назад", callback_data='Referal')
            markup.add(item1)

            msg = bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,"Введите ваш код")
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg,active)`

Comment: `def active(message):
                if msg == r:
                    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'успех!', reply_markup=markup)
                else:
                    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'не успех!', reply_markup=markup)

                bot.delete_message(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id)
                bot.polling(none_stop=True)`

Comment: А попробуйте функцию в начало перенести

Comment: Ну что там? Ну как?

Comment: да, вроде бы получилось, спасибо

Comment: а как записать сообщение юзера в переменную?